# What is the top-7 tag for?

Tags: discussion, tagging

What is the top-7 tag for?  Top 7 what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's referring to the link at the top of the page, [*The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).  It allows you to quickly identify the questions on meta that have to do with defining the basic site attributes.

The seven attributes are:

1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?
2. What should our FAQ contain?
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?
4. What should our domain name be?
5. What should our logo and site design look like?
6. Who should the moderators be?
7. How do we promote our site?

Please, help tag these items `top-7` so we can get to them quickly!